# How to pass different values from a CSV parameter file

Tags: jmeter

Please could someone tell me how I can pass parameter values to .json body:
I have a .csv data file like:
A
B
C

and I need to pass only data A for the request and sometimes both A & B in the next request and sometimes send all 3 and so on…
Thanks,
N

Answer (score 0):

- If you're using [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) - given default [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) of `All threads` each JMeter thread will read next line on each iteration. If you're OK with this - you can declare 3 variables but use 1 or 2 of them depending on the nature of the request.
- If you're using [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) - it's you who chooses which column to read and when to proceed to the next line
- Absolute freedom provides [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) where you can travel back and forth between rows and, choose whatever column of whatever row and transform the data in any way you can think of. The only disadvantage is that each virtual user will be reading the whole file in memory causing large memory footprint

Comment: Thanks, Dmitri. I have only one column. In the first row, the value is A, second row value B & so on.  But in the request, I need to pass random combination of values in .json body like:         … value: {A}..  sometimes and like …value: {A,C} sometimes and …value:{B,C} and so on

Comment: I'm not telepathic enough to guess that your CSV is one column while you're posting it as one row. Anyway you can go for option 3, example function syntax would be something like: `${__groovy(values = new File('test.csv').readLines(); payload = new HashSet(); 0.upto(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0\, values.size())\, {payload.add(values.get(org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextInt(0\, values.size())))});return  new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString(),)}`. More information: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thanks, Dimitri. I am sorry I didn't explain it properly